# Check if value exist in array of objects

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Given this object: http://kopy.io/H2CqY

I need to check if some card_id already exists in the visitor's array. How do I do so? I tried it with a loop but that didn't work because when I get a new data.card_id and there are already multiple entries in the visitors array it might not match.

My code:

```js
    $scope.$on("addMultiVisitor", function(evt, data) {

      $scope.newVisit.visitors.length + 1;
      $scope.newVisit.visitors.push({
        "access_route_id": "",
        "card_id": data.id,
        "identity_id": data.identity.id,
        "company_id": data.company.id,
        "company_name": data.company.name,
        "firstname": data.identity.given_names,
        "lastname": data.identity.surname,
        "birthdate": new Date(data.identity.birthdate)
      });
      window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
      $scope.$apply();
  });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `Array.some` method:

```
var doesIdExist = $scope.newVisit.visitors.some(function(v) {
    return v.card_id === data.id;
});
```

If anything in the array matches the condition, `true` will be the result, else `false`.

Comment: But remember about browser support, 'some' is IE >= 9 https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

Comment: @PawełKozikowski - True, I hope by this point everyone is developing for >= IE9 by now

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your object already exist in your array with `indexOf()`.

If the object is not in the array, it will return -1:

```
$scope.o = {
    "access_route_id": "",
    "card_id": data.id,
    "identity_id": data.identity.id,
    "company_id": data.company.id,
    "company_name": data.company.name,
    "firstname": data.identity.given_names,
    "lastname": data.identity.surname,
    "birthdate": new Date(data.identity.birthdate)
}

if($scope.newVisit.visitors.indexOf(o) == -1) { // Not in the array
     $scope.newVisit.visitors.push(o);
}
```

But I guess *[@tymeJV answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41103829/4927984)* fits your need better.